# Select drop down option using Selenium. Headless chrome. Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to select an option from a drop down menu that expands the records on a page. It works fine when I am not running headless. When I run in headless I get a timeout exception error while the page waits to find the element.

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uxTabContracts$uxTabPanelWaintingApproval$uxGridList$ctl05$uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate$uxDropDownListPageSize" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$uxTabContracts$uxTabPanelWaintingApproval$uxGridList$ctl05$uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate$uxDropDownListPageSize\',\'\')', 0)" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_uxTabContracts_uxTabPanelWaintingApproval_uxGridList_uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate_uxDropDownListPageSize">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="100">100</option>
                <option value="250">250</option>
                <option value="500">500</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="1000">1000</option>

            </select>
```

I have tried using the XPATH, the ID, and Name.

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_uxTabContracts_uxTabPanelWaintingApproval_uxGridList_uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate_uxDropDownListPageSize"]'))) # wait for option to expand page
    ExpandRecords = Select(chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_uxTabContracts_uxTabPanelWaintingApproval_uxGridList_uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate_uxDropDownListPageSize"]')) # define element to expand page
    ExpandRecords.select_by_value('1000') # select page size option from dropdown
```

The expected result is to select '1000' records and that the page will expand and move on to the next piece of code which will select the necessary records I need. What happens is nothing. and I get a timeout exception.

```
line 289, in Import_To_CRM
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_uxTabContracts_uxTabPanelWaintingApproval_uxGridList_uxUCGridViewPagingTemplate_uxDropDownListPageSize"]'))) # wait for option to expand page
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: cant you just run some javascript to directly set the value ? so `document.getElementById("selectionid").value = 1000`

Comment: What headless browser driver are you using?  PhantomJS?

Comment: @JohnGordon - I am using Chromedriver version 78. running Selenium, written in python.

Comment: @WilliamBright - not sure how but I will see if i can find a way to try it.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, how is that headless?  I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @JohnGordon - There are options to run headless version of chrome. 

    {options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless=True
    prefs = {
    "download.default_directory": r"M:\filepath",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True}
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    chromedriver = (r"C:\filepath\chromedriver.exe")
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, options=options)}

Comment: Are you sure that `select` is visible and actual dropdown implemented in different elements like `div`? Also check if `select` is inside an `iframe`? Can you share the url?

Comment: @sers - Cant share the URL, It's an internal CRM. My issue is that it finds the element when I am turn off the headless option and run with an open window. So the issue is I can't actually see it when it is running headless to see the behavior differences.

Comment: Try @Kunduk solution with chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080'); and driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `headless` browser you have to set the window size to fire on event.Because headless browser can't recognize where to click without window size.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
```

If above option doesn't work then check if the website is blocking in headless mode using

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you for the input, I didnt realize that running it headless would alter window size.