# Unable to click on the download link with js backend

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

There is a link on a website that downloads a csv file. The link is in a table but the actual download link is hidden.

```
<div id="testjs">
    <div test-example="">
        <table test-example="">
            <tr test-example="">
                <th test-example="">Car</th>
                <th test-example="">File</th>
            </tr>
            <tr test-example="">
                <td test-example="">Ford</td>
                <td test-example="">
                    <a test-example="" href="#">ford.csv</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying automate file download by scraping the site using python/selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.example.com")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('ford.csv')
```

When the last line above runs the script returns:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="<example session string>", element="<example element string>")>
```

When I run the code below nothing happens:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('ford.csv').click()
```

How do I get the file to download?

Comment: Use Chrome Headless browser instead of  PhantomJS

Comment: Have you got any solution yet for your problem using chrome?

Comment: I was partially able to solve my issue using chrome driver but not headless. DebanjanB’s solution did work. However there was a ‘allow cookies’ pop up that was getting in the way of the download link that I had to click first. The problem with headerless chrome was nothing downloaded. When chrome was not headless the file downloaded.

Comment: Check this answer for headless chrome see if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58770745/select-drop-down-option-using-selenium-headless-chrome-python/58772145#58772145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there isn't any issue with the following line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('ford.csv')
```

However at this point it is worth to mention that the *dot* character **`.`** always have a special effect/meaning.

---

Assuming you intend to `click()` on the element with text as **ford.csv** which is adjacent to the element with text as **Ford**, as a solution you can:

- Split the text `ford.csv` into two parts `ford` and `csv` and use within a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)
- As you intent to invoke `click()`, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()`
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr[test-example] td:nth-child(2)>a[test-example]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(., 'ford') and contains(.,'csv')]"))).click()
    ```
  - **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

    ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    ```

Comment: With these approaches I get the same error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a test-example="" href="#">...</a> is not clickable at point (X, Y). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: To address ElementClickInterceptedException follow the discussions 1)[selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741875/selenium-common-exceptions-elementclickinterceptedexception-message-element-cl/57749551#57749551) 2) [Element MyElement is not clickable at point (x, y)… Other element would receive the click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724185/element-myelement-is-not-clickable-at-point-x-y-other-element-would-receiv/44724688#44724688)

Comment: Thanks the issue was a ‘allow cookies’ pop up that was getting in the way. So I used your solution to allow cookies first and then download the file.

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is not supported in new Selenium version, consider user other driver. For your problem there were a bug clicking Button with JS.

Try this, I found in my selenium library to click_js buttons

```
item = driver.find_element_by_link_text('ford.csv')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click().perform()
```

Comment: Ok i've tried using this approach with headerless chrome but nothing happens. Got any ideas?